# Compare .NET Objects - Compare 2 lists

Tags: c#, .net, compare, compare-net-objects

I have 2 lists of objects. How can I ignore some properties of Car when it is doing the comparison? I have tried MembersToIgnore and AttributesToIgnore but it does not seem to recognize it and it still returns those properties in the differences. When I just try to compare 2 Cars it works just fine, how can I ignore the properties when I am comparing lists?

```
List<Car> lst1
List<Car> lst2

CompareLogic compare = new CompareLogic();
ComparisonResult res = compare.Compare(lst1,lst2);
```

Comment: If this is about using [this library](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects) then you should mention that fact.

Comment: @Kirk: I've created and added the tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Custom comparer](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects/wiki/Custom-Comparers).

For example:

```cs
public class SpecialCarComparer: BaseTypeComparer
{
    public SpecialCarComparer(RootComparer rootComparer) : base(rootComparer)
    {
    }

    public SpecialCarComparer() : this(RootComparerFactory.GetRootComparer())
    {
    }

    public override bool IsTypeMatch(Type type1, Type type2)
    {
        return type1 == typeof(Car);
    }

    public override void CompareType(CompareParms parms)
    {
        Car car1 = parms.Object1 as Car;
        Car car2 = parms.Object2 as Car;
        

        if (car1?.SomeCarProperty != car2?.SomeCarProperty || car1?.AnotherCarProperty > 100 || car2?.AnotherCarProperty < 100)
        {
            AddDifference(parms);
        }
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```cs
CompareLogic compareLogic = new CompareLogic();
compareLogic.Config.CustomComparers.Add(new SpecialCarComparer());
ComparisonResult result = compareLogic.Compare(obj1, obj2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using CompareNETObjects 4.79.0 and it works like a charm. I am able to compare complex types with sub-types while ignoring multiple fields or sub-types with following comparison config

Ex obj

```
ComplexPerson complexPerson1 = new ComplexPerson
{
    Id = "complexPers1",
    Date = new DateTime(2020, 2, 1),
    Person = new Person
    {
        Name = "Foo",
        LastName = "Bar"
    },
    Address = new Address
    {
        Street = "Street 1",
        PostalCode = "4321",
        City = "New York"
    },
    Batch = new Batch
    {
        Id = 1,
        Date = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1),
    }
};

ComplexPerson complexPerson2 = new ComplexPerson
{
    Id = "complexPers2",
    Date = new DateTime(2020, 2, 1),
    Person = new Person
    {
        Name = "Foo",
        LastName = "Bar"
    },
    Address = new Address
    {
        Street = "Street 2",
        PostalCode = "4321",
        City = "New York"
    }
};
ComparisonConfig complexComparisonConfig = new ComparisonConfig
{
  IgnoreObjectTypes = true,//will compare properties and ignore type of the types
  MembersToIgnore = new List<string> { nameof(ComplexPerson.Id), nameof(ComplexPerson.Batch), nameof(ComplexPerson.Address.Street) }
    };
ComparisonResult comparisonResult = new CompareLogic(comparisonConfig).Compare(complexPerson1, complexPerson2); //comparisonResult.AreEqual will be true
```

But here I am typicaly comparing one object with another, not lists. For comapring lists why not do a linq join to find matches in both lists and then compare two objects to one another?